# an equity of weighted $\ell^2$ norms

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{f_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{g_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two sequences such that $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} f_i^2 = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} g_i^2$.

Given two positive sequence $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ and there exist positive constant $c,C$ such that $c a_i \leq b_i \leq C a_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb
{N}$, denoted as $a_i \asymp b_i$.

For simplicity, assume $a_i,b_i$ decrease monotonically.

Do we have $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} a_i^2 f_i^2 \asymp \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} b_i^2 g_i^2$, possibly with some other constants?

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated the answer is no.

Let us consider a given positive sequence $(\lambda_i)_{i\ge 0}$ such that
$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda_i^2<+\infty$. Define  $(f_i)_{i\ge 0}$ and $(g _i)_{i\ge 0}$ as follows
$$f_{i}=\cases{\lambda_{i/2}&  if $i$ is even\cr
0& if $i$ is odd}\qquad
g_{i}=\cases{0& if $i$ is even\cr
\lambda_{(i-1)/2}& if $i$ is odd}$$

Clearly we have $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty f _i^2=\sum_{i=0}^\infty g_i^2=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda_i^2$$
Now, suppose $ a_i= b_i$ for every $i$ so that the condition on the sequences $(a_i)_{i\ge 0}$ and $(b_i)_{i\ge 0}$ is trivially satisfied with $c=C=1$.

But
$$ 
A=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i^2f_i^2=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{2i}^2\lambda_i^2,\qquad
B=\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i^2g_i^2=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{2i+1}^2\lambda_i^2
$$
Now, we may have $A<\infty$ and $B=\infty$, just take $a_{2i}=1,a_{2i+1}=1/\lambda_i$, and 
we may have $A=\infty$ and $B<\infty$, just take $a_{2i+1}=1,a_{2i}=1/\lambda_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i missed something , but lets assume, if you know nothing about $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$,that the sums converge. Otherwise, you cant make any assumptions about convergence (monotonically decreasing is surely not enough). If they converge, it easy follows that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}b_i^2g_i^2  \leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C^2a_i^2g_i^2=C^2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_i^2f_i^2 $ and the other way around. But I guess thats already clear to you?

Comment: why does the last equality hold? we only know the serieses are equal but not $g_i = f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

No, consider the basis vectors $e_n$ and $e_0$, which have the same norm. The weighted norm will be smaller for $e_n$ than $e_0$. In fact the weighted norm of $e_n$ converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is false. Suppose, to reach a contradiction, that it is true. Define $(f_i) = 1,0,0,0,\dots,$ $(g_i) = 0,1,0,0,0,\dots.$ Then $\sum f_i^2 = \sum g_i^2.$ For each $n= 2,3,\dots$ we can let both $(a_i),(b_i)$ be the sequence $1,1/n,1/(2n),1/(3n),\dots$ The conclusion then implies there exists positive constant $D$ such that

$$\tag 1 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2f_i^2 = 1 \le D\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i^2g_i^2 = Db_2^2 = Da_2^2 = \frac{D}{n^2},$$

for all $n.$ That is clearly impossible and we have reached the desired contradiction.